# "Editor Assigned" for 12 days after acceptance. Is this normal? If so, how long can this step take? When can I expect the proofs?

Tags: publications

A manuscript of mine was accepted by a Springer journal on January 2020 provided that I executed some corrections indicated by one of the reviewers in the second round of reviews. No further reviews or responses were requested by the reviewers. They told me that the manuscript was going to be passed to Production after that. I submitted my final version on February. The next day, the status changed to "Editor Assigned" and has remained unchanged for the last 12 days. Is this normal? If so, how long can this step take? When can I expect to receive the proofs?

Comment: They know. Ask the editor. But the term "editor" is applied to a wide variety of positions.

Comment: Thanks a lot Buffy, you are always here giving great answers. So I shouldn't wait like one more month? Would it be OK to ask the journal already?

Comment: In "editor time" a week is like a nanosecond. Patience is good unless you have a reason for knowing - i.e. you need to take some action based on the answer. But patience is finite, also.

Comment: I'll be patient! I suposse they need to see my last revision, because reviewers aren't going to see it...